# Rotate GameObject towards Line

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, rotation, quaternions

**Goal:** Given two 3D vectors, rotate a box, that's being spawned in between both vectors `Vector3.Lerp(A, B, 0.5f)`, so that it's aligned with the line defined by the vertices. The "box" itself is basically a *2D-Canvas GameObject* (i.e. Sprite), but it's being spawned in a 3D world.

Please also refer to the images below.

[image: Rotation of GameObject towards Line]

Keep in mind that this is a 3D problem, so all of this occurs e.g. on the surface of a cube.

[image: 3D Rotation of GameObject]

One idea was to somehow take the cross vector of the two vertices and align the RectTransform.rotation to it by using either Quaternion.LookRotation() or the Quaternion.RotateTowards-method, but since I'm fairly new to all of this I'd appreciate any hint.

Comment: Please put this information in the question body itself. The rotated coordinate system of the box can be constructed from 1) the displacement vector between the two points, 2) the normal of the surface this is performed on, and 3) their cross-product. No need to use a quaternion as the rotation matrix can be directly constructed from these three coordinate vectors.

Comment: As Meow said, we need to know the relationship between the vectors and the box; "it spawns between them" is insufficient.  Assuming you meant 'vectors' of directional data and not 'points' of positional data.  A code example of your current attempt would be ideal!

Comment: Try this: Compute vector from A to B and use: `Quaternion.LookRotation(AtoB, Vector3.up)`. You can also change `up` direction to one of `back, down, forward, left, right`. Let us know if it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You want to align the X-axis of the Canvas, to the direction `(B - A)`.

Mathematically, there are infinite ways to align only one axis with a given direction, so you need to specify a second alignment rule (usually, an UP vector).

The documentation of [Quaternion.LookRotation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html) says:

> Z axis (of the rotated object) will be aligned with forward, X axis (of the rotated object) aligned with cross product
>   between forward and upwards, and Y axis (of the rotated object) aligned with cross product
>   between Z and X.

From the point of view of the Canvas (when correctly orientated) the Z axis goes towards the center of the cube, so...

```
// This is the direction from the Box to the center of the cube
Vector3 boxToCube = Vector3.Cross(B - A, Vector3.up);
// So this should be the correct orientation of the Canvas
Quaternion orientation = Quaternion.LookRotation(boxToCube, Vector3.up);
```